# How to round up a timestampdiff in sql

Tags: sql, db2

I have a complex sql file where I am calculating timestampdiff as follows in seconds:

```
timestampdiff(2, char(max(END_TS) - min(START_TS))) as ELAPSED_TIME
```

ELAPSED_TIME is sometimes calculated as 0 when the difference is in microseconds. Is it possible to round off to 1 second if the difference is in microseconds so ELAPSED_TIME is never equal to 0?

Example:

```
[db2inst1@dashmpp-head-0 - Db2wh ~]$ db2 "select * from TEST_TBL"

COL1                       COL2                      
-------------------------- --------------------------
2022-01-25-01.00.00.300000 2022-01-25-01.00.00.000000

  1 record(s) selected.
```

```
[db2inst1@dashmpp-head-0 - Db2wh ~]$ db2 "select CEILING(timestampdiff(2, char(max(col1) - min(col2)))) from TEST_TBL"

1          
-----------
          0

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Since the difference is `300000` microseconds its equal to 0 seconds. Can we round this up to 1 second?

This is part if a long select query so I cannot use if else.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the expression as is or create a user defined scalar function based on this expression.

```
WITH TEST_TBL (COL1, COL2) AS 
(
VALUES
  (TIMESTAMP ('2022-01-25-01.00.00.300000'), TIMESTAMP ('2022-01-25-01.00.00.000000'))
, (TIMESTAMP ('2022-01-25-01.00.00.000000'), TIMESTAMP ('2022-01-25-01.00.00.000000'))
, (TIMESTAMP ('2022-01-25-01.00.02.000000'), TIMESTAMP ('2022-01-25-01.00.00.000000'))
)

SELECT
  COL1, COL2
-- the expression
, DECODE (COL1, COL2, 0, COALESCE (NULLIF (TIMESTAMPDIFF (2, CHAR (COL1 - COL2)), 0), 1)) AS DIFF
FROM TEST_TBL
```

| COL1 | COL2 | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-25-01.00.00.300000 | 2022-01-25-01.00.00.000000 | 1 |
| 2022-01-25-01.00.00.000000 | 2022-01-25-01.00.00.000000 | 0 |
| 2022-01-25-01.00.02.000000 | 2022-01-25-01.00.00.000000 | 2 |

## Update:

You may try the folloing as well:

```
CEIL (TIMESTAMPDIFF (1, CHAR (COL1 - COL2)) / 1000000.)
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I tried adding this to my script but got - `SQL0119N  An expression starting with "END_TS" specified in a SELECT clause, \nHAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or \nit is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column \nfunction and no GROUP BY clause is specified.  SQLSTATE=42803\n\n`.



I added  `DECODE (END_TS, START_TS, 0, COALESCE (NULLIF (TIMESTAMPDIFF (2, CHAR (max(END_TS) - min(START_TS))), 0), 1)) as ELAPSED_TIME`

Comment: Was able to run the query on my TEST_TBL though.

Comment: My sql script has the select statement with GROUP BY clause at the end and its not grouping on ELAPSED_TIME.

Comment: I provided just an expression. If you need to use some aggregation functions, you must change **every** occurrence of some particular column accordingly. That is: `DECODE (max (END_TS), min (START_TS), 0, COALESCE (NULLIF (TIMESTAMPDIFF (2, CHAR (max (END_TS) - min (START_TS))), 0), 1)) as ELAPSED_TIME`.